# Cocoa and printing only some NSViews

Tags: cocoa, printing, nsview

In Cocoa is there a way to disable printing for certain views?
I have a main window for which I don't want printing to be enabled in the menu, where for a preview window I want printing to be enabled?

I could do it programmatically (Check which window is active and bind that to the enabled binding), but - hey - this is Cocoa. Can that be done more easily? I have already consulted the NSView documentation, but can't find any information about that.